# How can I make a second product page in the same store?

Tags: magento-enterprise, product-page, ee-1.14.0.1

I've gotten a request to allow for duplicate product pages in a store.  They have many reasons for doing this.  The main reason, I believe, is for email and marketing targeting.

So they would like to have one product page, i.e. "store.com/product-page", that is the regular page.  Shows up in search, category pages, etc.  But then there would be another page, i.e. "store.com/marketing/product-page", that would show the same product, except maybe add a block with coupon information.

I've tried a number of different approaches, including adding the product to a new category with a different design, and trying to recreate the product page as a CMS page.  I feel like I'm overthinking it and there is a simple solution to this problem.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, we have figured something out that will work. According to Magento support this is expected behavior. Product pages with unique designs are meant to be clicked to from the category page. So they don't display the custom design unless they come from that category page link.

However, we have found a way around that restriction. You can direct link to a product and get the custom design by attaching a querystring variable to the URL for the category ID.  So your final link would look something like this:

store.com/newdesign/shirt?category=101

Answer (score 2):

I believe you could have 1 product and just have multiple category pages and associate the product with those pages and then you can add your widgets etc.. to the category page.

Comment: When we tried this, it didn't work quite right.  For example, if we have  product "shirt" in category "apparel", and then add that product to category "newdesign", then I would think you could access the product 3 ways:

store.com/shirt
store.com/apparel/shirt
store.com/newdesign/shirt

I would expect the first two to have the original design and the last to have the new design.  But unless I go to "store.com/newdesign" category first, the new design doesn't show up on "store.com/newdesign/shirt".  It's like it is waiting for a cookie from the category page.  Maybe I'm missing something there.

Comment: I have a similar scenario going on and it 100% works fine.  I have 1 product that is in multiple categories and one of the categories has a custom page design.  Works perfectly.

Comment: So if you go to an incognito window and go directly to the product page that should have the custom design without going to any other page, it shows the custom design?   In my above example, when I go straight to "store.com/newdesign/shirt" with a fresh incognito window, it doesn't show my custom design.